# How to determine if a linux symbolic link points to a directory or a file

Tags: linux, symlink-traversal

I have a directory that has symbolic links - some of them point to files and some of them to directories - how do I identify the ones poiting to directory in a shell script ( without any prejudice to names offcourse)

Comment: Use `readlink` to get the target of the symlink.

Comment: Thanks.   ls -L <link>  and ls \`readlink <link>\` seem to be identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ls -L  option to follow symlinks

This is the script that I used to differentiate between directories with contents from files/empty directories 
( this will work only if directory has some contents -- in my case I am anyway interested in those  directories that have some content so I am happy - but do suggest better options if any

```
cd dir
for i in `ls `
do
      if [ 1 -lt   `ls -l -L $i  | wc -l`  ]
      then
              echo "$i is a non empty directory" 
      else
              echo "$i is either an empty directory or a  file"
      fi
done
```